# Make array elements lowercase with Liquid filters for sorting

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I can't figure out how case-insesitively to sort an array containing strings:
`["A", "C", "E", "b", "d"]` into `["A", "b", "C", "d", "E"]`.

```
{% assign input = "A,C,E,b,d" | split:"," %}
{{ input | join: "-" }}
{{ input | map: 'downcase' | join: "-" }}
{{ input | map: 'downcase' | sort | join: "-" }}
{{ input | map: 'length' | join: "-" }}
{{ input | map: 'size' | join: "-" }}
```

What am I missing about `map:`?

Expected output:

```
A-C-E-b-d
a-c-e-b-d
a-b-c-d-e
1-1-1-1-1
1-1-1-1-1
```

Actual output:

```
A-C-E-b-d
----
----
----
----
```

Note: at first I tried `map: downcase` (without quotes), but got *no implicit conversion from nil to integer*.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: What a downvoter !!! Not even a comment to explain. You'd better read the question twice, or maybe write an answer if you can. Tiresome !

Comment: It would be nice to be able to address "these people" as @downvoter

Comment: This human nature. Haters are everywhere in our life. Let's keep doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sort_natural` [filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/sort_natural/) does a case-insensitive sort:

```
{% assign my_array = "zebra, octopus, giraffe, Sally Snake" | split: ", " %}

{{ my_array | sort_natural | join: ", " }}
```

Outputs `giraffe, octopus, Sally Snake, zebra`

Comment: `sort_natural` was added in [PR](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/pull/554) in [Liquid 4.0.0](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/master/History.md#400--2016-12-14--branch-4-0-stable) which was used by [Jekyll 3.5.0](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/commit/793405c00c5f2f23454a88f0c4057029a8d154f4) first, and became available in [gh-pages v147](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/releases/tag/v147) ([Liquid 4.0.0 commit in v147](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/commit/79d82eb45405503f), [Jekyll 3.5.0 commit in v147](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/commit/add5ab0f3218f211779)).

Answer (score 3):

*`sort_natural` was added after I asked the question. See [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66354439/253468) answer. I'll leave this answer here, because it shows how can you do a sorting by any key.*

```
{% assign input = "A,C,E,b,d" | split:"," %}
{% capture intermediate %}{% for entry in input %}{{ entry | downcase }}&#x1F;{{ entry }}{% unless forloop.last %}&#x1E;{% endunless %}{% endfor %}{% endcapture %}
{% assign intermediate_sorted = intermediate | split:'&#x1E;' | sort %}
{% capture sorted %}{% for entry in intermediate_sorted %}{{ entry | split: '&#x1F;' | last }}{% unless forloop.last %}&#x1E;{% endunless %}{% endfor %}{% endcapture %}
{% assign sorted = sorted | split: '&#x1E;' %}
{{ sorted | join: "-" }}
```

will output `A-b-C-d-E`.

The **US ([Unit Separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_separator), [\u001F](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/001f/index.htm), not [\u241F](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/241f/index.htm))** and **RS ([Record Separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_separator), [\u001E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/001e/index.htm), not [\u241E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/241e/index.htm))** are the two characters unlikely to appear in the input, so they can be used safely most of the time. They could be `,` and `|` if you want to sort CSS IDs for example.

Comment: The true nature of Liquid :) ... without custom filters of course